# golang windows service fails without any error

Tags: go, windows-services

I have written a simple windows service using golang.

```
package main

import "golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc"
import "io/ioutil"
import "log"
import "encoding/json"
import "time"
import "strconv"
import "os"
import "./cmd"
import "golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc/eventlog"
import "fmt"

type myservice struct{}

func (m *myservice) Execute(args []string, r <-chan svc.ChangeRequest, changes chan<- svc.Status) (ssec bool, errno uint32) {
    log.Println("Starting service")
    const cmdsAccepted = svc.AcceptStop | svc.AcceptShutdown | svc.AcceptPauseAndContinue
    changes <- svc.Status{State: svc.StartPending}
    changes <- svc.Status{State: svc.Running, Accepts: cmdsAccepted}
    StartService(r, changes)
    return
}

//RunService Runs the current application as a service.It will send the necessary flags to windows.
func RunService(maintServiceName string) {
    //var elog eventlog

    elog, evtErr := eventlog.Open(maintServiceName)
    if evtErr != nil {
        return
    }

    defer elog.Close()
    log.Println("Running service")
    elog.Info(1, fmt.Sprintf("starting %s service", maintServiceName))

    run := svc.Run
    sererr := run(maintServiceName, &myservice{})
    if sererr != nil {
        elog.Error(1, fmt.Sprintf("%s service failed: %v", maintServiceName, sererr))
    }
}

//StartService Starts the Service
func StartService(r <-chan svc.ChangeRequest, changes chan<- svc.Status) {
    const cmdsAccepted = svc.AcceptStop | svc.AcceptShutdown | svc.AcceptPauseAndContinue
    jsonFile, err := os.Open("config.json")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("No configuration found")
    }
    byteVal, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(jsonFile)
    var result map[string]interface{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(byteVal), &result)
    var serverURL = result["serverURL"]
    var serviceName = result["serviceName"]
    var intervalStr = result["interval"].(string)
    var intervalInt, parseErr = strconv.ParseInt(intervalStr, 10, 32)
    if parseErr != nil {
        intervalInt = 60
    }

    log.Println("server Url ", serverURL)
    log.Println("service name ", serviceName)

    cmd.SetServerURL(serverURL.(string))
    cmd.SetServiceName(serviceName.(string))
    log.Println("Running Thread")

    go func() {
        for {
            log.Println("sleeping ")
            time.Sleep(time.Duration(intervalInt) * time.Second)
            cmd.Connect()
        }
    }()

    select {
    case c := <-r:
        if c.Cmd == svc.Stop || c.Cmd == svc.Shutdown {
            break
        }
        if c.Cmd == svc.Interrogate {
            changes <- c.CurrentStatus
            time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
            changes <- c.CurrentStatus
        }
        if c.Cmd == svc.Pause {
            changes <- svc.Status{State: svc.Paused, Accepts: cmdsAccepted}
        }
        if c.Cmd == svc.Continue {
            changes <- svc.Status{State: svc.Running, Accepts: cmdsAccepted}
        }
    }

}
```

The application mostly runs without issues for mostly a day or two but stops after that without any errors. There are no logs after sleeping line in the log when it happens. Can I add anything to get more info about the service failure. What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by adding a loop around the `select` in `StartService` (see [this example](https://github.com/golang/sys/blob/master/windows/svc/example/service.go#L31)). From the code you have provided it looks like your service will exit after receiving any signal (including pause/Interrogate) which may be the issue. Adding some further logging in `StartService` may also be beneficial (anything that provides more info on what is happening helps!)

If that does not solve the issue then its worth adding a [defer/recover](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Handling_panics) in the go routine and `StartService` to check if a panic is causing the issue (just writing something to the log is probably sufficient).

Comment: Yes, the service received an interrogate signal and it quit.

Comment: And to verify immediately that this is the problem, one can run `sc interrogate servicename`. After fixing, did the same and the service did not stop.

Comment: Great - hopefully the service will stay up now. I generally find it worth logging when a service stops and why (including if via a panic) because without this info its hard to track down any intermittent issues.